# Rewriterule breaks absolute path of resource loading

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have an `.htaccess` that points to two different router, one for the **frontend** and one for the **api**s

```
<ifModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

  RewriteRule ^(?!api\/).* frontend/router.php [QSA,NC]
  RewriteRule ^api/.* backend/router.php [QSA,NC]

</ifModule>
```

The routes works perfectly but my problem is that, in a view, when I try to load some resource like:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/assets/css/normalize.css" charset="utf-8"/>
```

It does not work because `assets` is under `/frontend` and not under the actual root `/`.

How can I change the root path of each directory? What I would like to achieve is that `/` in `link` points to `frontend` and not to the parent folder.

I tried with `alias` and `aliasMatch` but with no luck.

This is my folder structure:

```
/
/backend
/frontend
.htacess
```

Hope it make sense to you.

Comment: Do you want this rule to affect only `/assets/` URLs?

Answer (score 0):

Solved using

```
RewriteRule ^assets/(.*)$ frontend/assets/$1 [L,NC]
```